# segmentation fault after manipulating c string with secondary pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm having a problem with c string, I want to keep address of original string aside and manipulate string using another c pointer, but it will give an segmentation fault when try to print that string using original or secondary pointer, however declaring string as character array does not present such fault. I don't to use array as well as I don't want to lose original address. Please point the problem.

```
/* segmentation fault when run */
char *string = "Hello World";
char *nick = string;
while(*nick)
    *nick++ = '0';
printf("%s\n", string);

/* display 000000000000 when run (wished result)*/
char array[] = "Hello World";
char *nick = array;
while(*nick)
    *nick++ = '0';
printf("%s\n", array);
```

Comment: String literals like "Hello World" may be (and often are) allocated in read-only memory. If you want a modifiable string, declare an array, and use the string to initialize the array.

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker , you mean there is no way to have a writeable string like mine *string?

Comment: You would allocate a writable buffer, like in your second code sample, or with `malloc()`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks, I picked great idea of malloc and strcpy to achieve results.

Comment: That works. You might also look at `strdup()`.

Comment: @Davislor yes, I read that too. Things were solved instantly after knowing that "char * string" is equal to "const char * string" and that we can only change address of pointer, not the content of pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code sample initializes your pointers to the start of a string constant.  Modifying a string constant is **undefined behavior**.

In fact, you should never, ever write `char *s = "hello world";`.  Always write `const char *s` or, better yet, `const char* const s` if it points to a string constant.  The only reason you’re even allowed to have a pointer that isn’t `const` alias a string constant is for backward-compatibility with code written before the `const` keyword existed.  There’s never any good reason to do it in new code.

The second code sample creates an array with static storage.  Modifying that array is fine.